# How to fix this dropdown navbar

Tags: html, css, nav

I am writing a navigation bar with a dropdown option.

I have 2 problems: I can't get the dropdown to position properly under the menu, + also when I try to move the mouse to click on the elements in the dropdown submenu it closes as soon as I move.
Can anyone suggest a fix?

Thanks

On codepen:

https://codepen.io/-royqooe/pen/GRxaVbm

```css
/* CSS section for home */

.navtop {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.navtop div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.navtop div h1,
.navtop div a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navtop div h1 {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 2%;
  color: #f5f8ff;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.navtop div a {
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c1c4c8;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navtop div a i {
  padding: 2px 8px 0 0;
}

.navtop div a:hover {
  color: #66ccff;
}


/* sequel for home and navbar */

nav.navtop {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.navtop>.navbar>ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navtop li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.navtop ul li ul {
  background: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.navtop ul li:hover>ul,
.navtop ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

.navtop ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .topbar-text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navlol navtop" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar">
    <h1>Websitee Title</h1>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.php"><i class="fa-solid fa-file"></i><span class="topbar-text">Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <ul class="dropdownnn">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navelements"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="profile.php"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><span class="topbar-text">Profile</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><span class="topbar-text">Logout</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got an easy fix for you:

add this

```
.navtop li {
  min-height:25px;
}
```

the issue is that that menu li was way shorter than the others to the sides due to the icons, even better maybe is instead adding this instead:

```
.navtop li {
  height:100%
}
```

both worked for me

Answer (score 1):

[In the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnr2v.jpg), the yellow color is the area that `<li>` element is covering. You can see there is a gap between `<li>` element and submenu. When you try to move the mouse to submenu, your cursor goes out of yellow area and the submenu hides.

The solution would be to position the submenu so it starts exactly after yellow area and make sure there is no gap. Apply margin-top of 0.5rem on submenu instead of 1rem.